# Extending new user creation form, Django

Tags: python, django, model

I am trying to work on adding a location field to the User Profile and associate it with a user. I currently have something like this:

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        location = models.CharField(('location'),max_length=30, blank=False)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

This is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django import forms
from UserProfile.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import *

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    username = forms.RegexField(label=("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$', help_text = ("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."),error_messages = {'invalid': ("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=("Password confirmation"), widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text = ("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))
    email = forms.EmailField(label=("Email address"))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(("A user with that username already exists."))

    def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    if email == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError((""))
    return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1", "")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(label=("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
        help_text = ("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages = {'invalid': ("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    location = forms.CharField(label=("Location"),max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        f = self.fields.get('user_permissions', None)
        if f is not None:
            f.queryset = f.queryset.select_related('content_type')


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'location')}),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions')}),
        (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        (('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    form = MyUserChangeForm

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

I do not fully understand Django/python code and I know something is missing from this code, because when I add a new user it doesn't save the Location field in the database. It saves the user id tho. I guess I am missing something like:

```
request.user.get_profile().location = self.cleaned_data["location"]
```

but I am not sure where to put it.

Comment: Your code seems to have wrong indention. It would be a lot easier for us to debug your code, if you correct the indention. One thing I noticed is that if you want email to be required, just pass required=True argument to it, instead of manually validating it.

Answer (score 3):

You may use Model Inheritance for that, which do similar things for you...

[Model Inheritance and proxy models...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

Comment: I would appreciate actual help with my code. I have read many different pages and in all of them people do different things. Reading more wont help me have a better understanding of the code.

Comment: Also Model Inheritance is not good in the case of django.contrib.auth, the extensions to the User model are expected to live in the UserProfile model.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use a simple inline for the profile? Yes, it will be shown at the bottom, but otherwise it would work.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from website.users.models import UserProfile

admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    max_num = 1

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'location')}),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions')}),
        (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        (('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )

admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: I did try that actually but I get this error and I dont know what it means or where it errors. `column user_id is not unique`

Comment: This is because you did not declare the 'user' field in the UserProfile class as a *-to-one. *Edit: oh dear, you have ideed declared as OneToOneField...*

Comment: Are you trying to insert more than one address? A user must have at most one profile, so add the 'max_num' option to the inline, as edited.

Comment: Sorry for a delayed reply :) I have finished with that project, but thank you for the attempt in helping! I really had a terrible experience with the built in django functions and hope I wont have to work with it again! :)